# Running web server along side Grafana with reverse proxy

Tags: web, nginx, reverse-proxy, grafana

I followed these steps below to setup Grafana on Ubuntu 18.04
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-grafana-on-ubuntu-16-04

One of the steps is to setup reverse proxy and load port 3000 for Grafana by default which is nice. However, I wish to load some php pages as well on the web server port (https only) maybe using a sub domain or custom port?

How can I do this? I’m not very familiar with the nginx hosts file as I’m used to Apache. Any help will be appreciated.

Grafana loads on: https://grafana.mysite.com
reverse proxy load to port 3000

So: 
Web server (html folder) should load on

https://manage.grafana.mysite.com 
or
https://grafana.mysite.com:1234
(custom port)

Thanks.

Comment: Post your nginx.conf and we can help more.

Comment: But there's no reason you can't have Grafana served from grafana.site.com and others from site.com